# NullReferenceException while running SharePoint products ( Central admin site is not working)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, exception-handling

We are able to access the sharepoint sites but the centeral admin is not working so tried to run the share point product with exsisting farm and sharepoint_configdb. After step7, we are getting error as NullReferenceException and product wizard failed. Not able to run centeral admin.

> Detailed Exception: 01/08/2013 16:07:36  19  ERR
>   Task applicationcontent has failed with an unknown exception 
>   01/08/2013 16:07:36  19  ERR                    Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.CopyAppDomainDirectories(DirectoryInfo
>   vrPath, OverwriteSetting overwrite)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ApplyApplicationContentToLocalServer()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ApplicationContentTask.Run()
>   at
>
> ### Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

please help us.